# Does having more widgets/things on screen when the screen is off or on use up more battery than if there was less?

Tags: battery, android-12

Let's say you had a timer widget that was counting down time. If you turn off the screen, would the widget be taking up more battery than if it wasn't on screen and was just in the background counting down time?

Generally, does having things going on in the main screen with either the screen on or off use up more battery, or does it not make a difference?

Comment: Static icons or widgets on home screen don't make any difference, at least not noticeable. But a widget can be dynamic - performing [periodic updates](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/advanced#periodic). It depends on the app developer. They may opt to update the widget when screen is off, doing some background work which affects battery life. But this behavior is not limited to widgets only. Any app can wake up the device and perform a necessary (from the developer's perspective) task. Or they may wait for the device to wake up.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks! I would like to ask about this specifically according to the clock/timer app which has a small widget/pop up showing the timer.

This means the timer would probably update in real time, so having the screen off but the widget on-screen might use up a bit more battery than if it was just in the background, but I'm not sure.

Comment: To be sure you need to observe the behavior of the app on device, or ask the developer.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Understandable, though in most cases I'll assume having those things on screen will take up just a tad bit more battery even with the screen off.